# object parsing using req parameter and save in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nested object which I am able to fetch properly but unable to store the the nested object values in the schema. Below are my code snippets:

## header.js Router File

```
router.post('',(req, res)=>{
    //console.log(req.body)
    const header = new headerModel({
        register:{
            name: req.body.name,
            url: req.body.url
        },
        logo:{
            image: req.body.image,
            altText: req.body.altText,
            url: req.body.url
        }
    })
    console.log(header)
})
module.exports = router
```

## Header.js Schema File

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const headerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    register: {
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        url: {
            type: String
        }
    },

    logo: {
        image: {
            type: String,
        },
        altText: {
            type: String
        },
        url: {
            type: String
        },

    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('header', headerSchema)
```

## JSON

```
{
"register":{
        "name":"Register",
        "url":"/register"
    },
"logo":{
    "image":"/imagePath/ab.png",
    "alttext":"Home",
    "url":"/"
}
}
```

I need to store the value of name and url in register and signin objects respectively in Router File

the header in Router File when logged on console doesn't include register or logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you get the data from JSON in the wrong way and you haven't saved the header yet. You can solve it by:

```
let header = new headerModel({
    register:{
        name: req.body.register.name,
        url: req.body.register.url
    },
    logo:{
        image: req.body.logo.image,
        altText: req.body.logo.altText,
        url: req.body.logo.url
    }
})
header.save(function (err, doc) {
  // Do some thing you want
})
```

Related information can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save).

Comment: Yes i haven't saved it yet because I am unable to fetch the values in the register and logo object when i log them on console

Comment: The JSON is what you get when `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: I get the correct json when i console.log(req.body) and also the properties of register but when i assign them respectively, and console.log(header), i only get the object with id and nothing else